# mysql comparing intergers

Tags: mysql, comparison

I was wondering if i can compare two intergers in my sql statement.
I have one date field, saved as unixtimestamp. I want to find those records where the date field is between two values.
Something like this:

```
Select ... From ... WHERE (dateField + myNumber) Between (x) And (y)
```

where myNumber is a variable from a loop function.

Is something like this possible?

**Edit:**
myNumber is always a positive number, greater than the datefield value

What i am trying to do is create a list of events that must happen again at some point in the future.
I have some records of logged events in my table. I run a query to find when those events must happen again in the future.

Lets say that i have 10 records that happened on March, 2011, I need to create a list of those 10 records that must happen again in March, 2012.

That's why i thought of the logic: [saved_date] + [1 year duration] Between [March 1, 2012] And [March 31, 2012]

It seemed simple enough since my dates are stored as unix timestamps.

Comment: Bohemian is right don't modify the field, you might have an index on it, and if you modify it your index won't be used

Comment: What exactly is your question? You posted a working SQL (though see Bohemian's answer for how to make it more efficient), so I don't see your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be inclined to *not* modify the field, but rather modify the range values, so you can still use an index (if one exists):

```
Select ... From ... WHERE dateField Between x - myNumber And y - myNumber
```

Comment: that will causing problem if `myNumber` is a negative number?

Comment: @ajureal - Certainly. Subtracting a negative number can break the space-time continuum.

Comment: @ajreal: No, it's equivalent transform. You see, those high school math lessons have their purpose.

Comment: @all -- sorry for ignorant, the negative number will be a problem or not?

Comment: @Bohemian: I thought of this, but I don't think this logic suits me.
What i am trying to do is determine when an event must happen again.
So, if i have the event happened at a specific date, I am trying to create a list of then the event must happen again in the future.
I have edited my original post with an example to better explain this

Comment: Just for the record, negative values for `mynumber` are fine.